# Hamburger Menu position in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, menu, native

i am trying to move the hamburger menu from left to right in react native. Unfortunately I can't.
Can anyone help me please ...? This is the code:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { DrawerActions } from '@react-navigation/native';
import pageArticle from "./pages/article";
import pageFeed from "./pages/feed";

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

const MyDrawer = () => {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator 
        initialRouteName="Feed"
        screenOptions={{
            drawerPosition: 'right',
        }}
    >
        <Drawer.Screen name="Feed" component={pageFeed}
        
        />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Article" component={pageArticle} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (  
    <NavigationContainer>
        <MyDrawer />
    </NavigationContainer>
    
  );
}
```

With the command drawerPosition: 'right', I can put the drawer on the right but not the hamburger menu.

Please... Help me...

Comment: There is no code related to position of hamburger menu. You need to look at code where your hamburger menu icon live :)

Comment: As Slava mentioned, it would be easier for us to help if you posted code for your menu icon as well. 

As a guess, is your hamburger icon absolutely positioned against a different relatively positioned item? It could be trying to position itself to the background, rather than the drawer.

Answer (score 0):

You can render a custom header component and put the menu button where ever you want.

```
   <Drawer.Navigator 
            initialRouteName="Feed"
            screenOptions={{
                drawerPosition: 'right',
                header: (props) => {
                    return <CustomHeaderComponent {...props}/>
              }
             }}
        >
```

Comment: Thanks... I will do it !!!